# Django can't login with valid credentials

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-login

Django doesn't login my user. I'm using a Django REST call to do this:

```
class UserLogin(APIView):

permission_classes = []

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate(
            username=request.data.get('email'),
            password=request.data.get('password')
        )
        print("User de Authenticate -> %s" % user)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user, backend='apps.core.api.backends.EmailAuthBackend')

            return HttpResponse("Valid")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid")
```

With my custom backend:

```
class EmailAuthBackend(object):
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
    """ Authenticate a user based on email address as the user name. """
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=username)
        if bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), user.password.encode('utf-8')):
            return user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

The point is that authenticate returns me the user if the credentials are valid, so the problem is not there. The login function its returning me None!
I do a little debug of login with prints, so, here is the django login function:

```
def login(request, user, backend=None):
"""
Persist a user id and a backend in the request. This way a user doesn't
have to reauthenticate on every request. Note that data set during
the anonymous session is retained when the user logs in.
"""
session_auth_hash = ''
print("1")
if user is None:
    user = request.user
if hasattr(user, 'get_session_auth_hash'):
    print("2")
    session_auth_hash = user.get_session_auth_hash()

if SESSION_KEY in request.session:
    print("3")
    if _get_user_session_key(request) != user.pk or (
            session_auth_hash and
            not constant_time_compare(request.session.get(HASH_SESSION_KEY, ''), session_auth_hash)):
        # To avoid reusing another user's session, create a new, empty
        # session if the existing session corresponds to a different
        # authenticated user.
        print("4")
        request.session.flush()
else:
    print("5")
    request.session.cycle_key()

try:
    print("6")
    backend = backend or user.backend
except AttributeError:
    print("7")
    backends = _get_backends(return_tuples=True)
    print("LOS BACKENDS -> %s" % backends)
    if len(backends) == 1:
        print("8")
        _, backend = backends[0]
    else:
        print("9")
        raise ValueError(
            'You have multiple authentication backends configured and '
            'therefore must provide the `backend` argument or set the '
            '`backend` attribute on the user.'
        )
else:
    print("10")
    if not isinstance(backend, str):
        print("11")
        raise TypeError('backend must be a dotted import path string (got %r).' % backend)

print("12")
request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = backend
request.session[HASH_SESSION_KEY] = session_auth_hash
print(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
if hasattr(request, 'user'):
    print("13")
    request.user = user
rotate_token(request)
user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
```

And the debug of the prints: 
1
2 
5 
6 
10 
12 
9 
13

I see that It raises the Value Error of backends, but I pass the backend on the login call and I have it imported in settings.py too. Don't know why django can't login my user. Anyone got a solution? EDIT, for more information: my User ->

```
class User(AbstractUser):

name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
surnames = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=60)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
country = CountryField()
phonenumber = PhoneNumberField()
postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=5)

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

Is implemented with AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'.
And my user creation method, I hash the password manually:

```
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.data["password"] = 
    bcrypt.hashpw(request.data["password"].encode(), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode()
    request.data["username"] = request.data["name"]
    print(request.data["username"])
    print(request.data["password"])
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: share your settings.py file

Comment: Here it is -> [linkToSettings](https://bitbucket.org/ivanlopezj/practicabackend/src/master/practicabackend/settings.py)

Answer (score 0):

correct your indentation

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate(
            username=request.data.get('email'),
            password=request.data.get('password')
        )
        print("User de Authenticate -> %s" % user)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user, backend='apps.core.api.backends.EmailAuthBackend')
            return HttpResponse("Valid")
   else:
       return HttpResponse("Invalid")
```

Comment: Yeah that's something to correct too, but the error login doesn't happen because of that, anyways, ty for share.

Answer (score 0):

Aparently you cannot login with a method of Django REST, so I changed the login code to a normal Django method, and with the same code I was able to login.